# How to specify files that depend on other files

Tags: cmake

I am pretty new to cmake and here is my CMakeLists.txt file on my project's root directory

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
project (Tools C)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror")
include_directories("include")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(lib/xstr.c PROPERTIES
                            OBJECT_DEPENDS "lib/xalloc.c")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(lib/counter.c PROPERTIES
                            OBJECT_DEPENDS "lib/xstr.c")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(lib/dynamic_array.c PROPERTIES
                            OBJECT_DEPENDS "lib/xalloc.c")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(lib/list.c PROPERTIES
                            OBJECT_DEPENDS "lib/xalloc.c")



add_executable(cat cat.c lib/xalloc.c lib/xfopen.c)
add_executable(counter counter.c lib/counter.c)
add_executable(darr dynamic_array.c lib/dynamic_array.c)
add_executable(linked list.c lib/list.c)
```

I keep c files that contains a `main()` function on my root directory. I keep other c files on `{project_root}/lib` directory.

My problem is that I am getting following error:

```
[ 33%] Built target cat
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target 'lib/xstr.c', needed by 'CMakeFi
les/counter.dir/lib/counter.c.obj'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/counter.dir/all' failed
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/counter.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:75: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make.exe: *** [all] Error 2
```

What I want to achieve is to link`{project_root}/cat.c` with `{project_root}/lib/xstr.c` and `{project_root}/lib/xalloc.c` etc.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Hi, do you have any feedback regarding my answer?

Answer (score 1):

You are taking cmake **far** too complicated! You have to set dependencies within targets, not source files. In your specific case, I suggest you add a few intermediate libraries. You can have them static so that the executable linking to them will not have problems in retrieving the linked library at runtime (the executable will integrate all the symbols and definitions he needs from the library).

Your code can be reduced as follow:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.8) # <<--2.6 is very outdated
project (Tools C)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-ansi -pedantic -Wall -Werror")
include_directories("include")

add_library(xalloc STATIC lib/xalloc.c)
add_library(xstr STATIC lib/xstr.c)

add_executable(cat cat.c lib/xfopen.c)
add_executable(counter counter.c lib/counter.c)
add_executable(darr dynamic_array.c lib/dynamic_array.c)
add_executable(linked list.c lib/list.c)

target_link_libraries(cat xalloc)
target_link_libraries(counter xstr xalloc) #xstr needs stuff from xalloc
target_link_libraries(darr xalloc)
target_link_libraries(linked xalloc)
```

Note: **Are you sure you need `darr` and `linked` as executables?** They look very much like a library... Also, having a file called counter.c and one lib/counter.c does not seem very safe (same for dynamic_array and list).

Some useful links:
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_library.html
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html